# Pass object method into multiprocessing Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a program:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def plus():
    for i in range(10):
        print("+")
        time.sleep(1)

def star():
    for i in range(10):
        print("%")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1=Process(target=plus)
    p1.start()
    p2=Process(target=star)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print('FINISH')
```

the output is more or less the same:

+&+&+&+&+&+&+&+&+&+& FINISH

I am trying to achieve the same passing object method into Process as follows:

```
import time

class Plus:
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            print("+")
            time.sleep(1)



import time

class Star:
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            print("&")
            time.sleep(1)



from Plus import Plus
from Star import Star
from multiprocessing import Process

class ThreadsCreation:
    def run(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            p = Plus()
            g = Star()
            process1 = Process(target=p.run())
            process2 = Process(target=g.run())
            process1.start()
            process1.join()
            process2.start()
            process2.join()
            print('FINISH')


ThreadsCreation().run()
```

In the second approach the output is always:
++++++++++&&&&&&&&&&FINISH

How to achieve the output of the first example with the object approach from the second one?

Comment: Just a note: your `ThreadsCreation` **creates no threads**.

Comment: Anyway, the issue is you are clalling `start` and `join` for a single process one after the other, this is, in effect, making it run *serially*. `.join` *blocks and waits for the process to terminate*

Comment: You are calling `p.run()` _before_ creating the process. Do `Process(target=p.run)` instead.

Comment: As an aside, you should do the `if __name__ == '__main__':` thing at module level before `ThreadsCreation().run()`. On windows, this module will be reimported in the created processes and you don't want that code executing again.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for help, now it works as expected

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for help, now it works as expected